# Encoding of special properties in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, utf-8, properties

I have an application which uses swedish language in some java and jsp pages.
Swedish words are described in `application.properties` file and those names will be used in the application.

Application Screen:

[image: Application Screen**strong text**]

Words which are defined in the properties file and the words which I am seeing in the jsp page is different.

```
button.search=Sök
```

I tried all content types in the settings. Still I am getting this error and because of this different words my application is not working in eclipse.

Could you please anyone tell me what changes I need to do in  eclipse to make this application work

Answer (score 2):

From your screenshot it looks like your properties file is encoded in UTF-8,
thus `ö` is represented by 2 bytes.

But properties files must be encoded in **ISO-8859-1** (optionally with `\uXXXX` escapes), not in UTF-8 or anything else.

Quoted from the javadoc of class
[`java.util.Properties`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html):

> The `load(Reader)` / `store(Writer, String)` methods load and store
>    properties from and to a character based stream in a simple
>    line-oriented format specified below. The `load(InputStream)` /
>    `store(OutputStream, String)` methods work the same way as the
>    `load(Reader)/store(Writer, String)` pair, except the input/output
>    stream is encoded in ISO 8859-1 character encoding.
>    Characters that cannot be directly represented in this encoding
>    can be written using Unicode escapes [...]

That means, you should store your `application.properties` file 
in ISO-8859-1 encoding. Or better yet, you should write

```
button.search=S\u00F6k
```

instead of

```
button.search=Sök
```

Using the `\uXXXX` escapes for all non-ASCII characters has the advantage
that you can store the file in UTF-8 or any ISO-8859-x, and you get the same
file content anyway.

Comment: I have used ISO 8859-1 enconding for the Application.properties file and in the jsp  and it is working fine. Now there is one more issue here. JSP will get the value from Application.properties file and the same value will be used in Action class. if I check the value in the action class I am getting the same issue as mentioned earlier

Comment: in short I am getting the issue while fetching the value from Application. properties in .java file.

Answer (score 2):

Just use Eclipse's Properties Editor. It saves a .properties file in the only allowed character encoding (ISO 8859-1) and \u escapes characters that are not in that character set.

It does have a hover display to show decoded codepoints but a view showing a table of name-value pairs would be nicer.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe change the workspace encoding will help. Go Window -> Preferences -> General -> Workspace and change the text file encoding to UTF8.

Answer (score -1):

Change you eclipse default content type:

**Window > Preferences > General > Content Types, set UTF-8 as the default encoding for all content types.**